# How to make hit area for android button ? like flash hit area

Tags: android

I want to know how to make 'hit area' for an android button.

I have a button with background image. This image is non-uniform shape. I want to make a 'hit area' and a 'non-hit area' -- the area with shape is the 'hit area', transparent area is 'non-hit area'.

The background image is composed of a transparent area and a non-transparent area.

Answer (score 0):

The only method is to put a view transparent above it and listen for touches in this 'ghost' view.